# Store returned array as a const

Tags: javascript, json

How do I set my returned data from a JSON file to a const so I can use it in other functions. I'm able to console.log but how do I proceed? The end goal is to be able to use data.purchase_orders and loop through the data (ie - price_list)

data.json

```
{
  "purchase_order": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "external_number": "1000",
      "status": "Created",
      "price_list": [
            {
               "id": "msrp",
               "name": "retail price",
               "currency": "USD"
               }
        ],
      "shipments": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "external_number": "10000",
                    "status": "Created",
                    "tracking_number": "Z1F2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "external_number": "9000",
                    "status": "In Transit",
                    "tracking_number": "PL21F"
                }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

index.html

```
<div id="shipments"></div>

<script>
const data_file = 'data.json';

async function fetchPO(){
  const reponse = await fetch(data_file);
  const data = await response.json();

  const PO = data.purchase_orders.forEach((PODetails) => {
    console.log(PODetails);
    //^this displays key and value of my JSON data_file
  })

  displayShipments(PO);
}

fetchPO();

function displayShipments(shipmentsList){
  document.getElementById("shipments").innerHTML = `
    ${Object.keys(shipmentsList).map(function (shipments) 

      return `<a href="#">${shipments.id}</a>
              <p>${shipments.tracking_number}</p>`
       )}
    }
  `
}

</script>
```

Comment: you can use `.map()` method to only include shipments property like, this: `const shipments = data.purchase_orders.map(po => detail => detail.shipments).flat()`. Then, call your `displayShipments(shipments)` function and pass it as arguments. Hope this help!

Comment: @DSPdav It's not really reusable? Eventually. I'll have other functions that will require to access data.purchase_orders as well.

Comment: since your goal only use `data.purchase_order.shipments` property, so store it to variable `const shipments` like I do is the easiest way to use it as arguments in function.

Comment: Sorry. I should have made my goal more clear. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to return the data from the async `fetccPO()` and store the promise in a variable.

A promise can be used as many times as you want.

Simplified example:

```js
async function fetchUsers() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  return response.json();
}

// makes request and stores promise in variable
const usersPromise = fetchUsers();


async function logAddress() {
  // promise can be used many times
  const users = await usersPromise;
  console.clear()
  console.log(users[0].address);
}

async function logUserName() {
  const users = await usersPromise;
  console.clear()
  console.log(users[0].name);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="logAddress()">Log first user address</button>
<button onclick="logUserName()">Log first user name</button>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Completely forgot that setting any const inside a function only lives inside the function.